# Find the next blank cell to past values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that can save me a lot of time repairing the old macros. What i am trying to do is to compare if a value located in "Mono risco 3" with "MonoBi") if it finds that value i want to past some values from "MonoBi" to "Bi recurso". I want to past that values in the end of a list that already exists. I think it is possible but i dont know how. I know the code is not optimized but i want it to run first and then correct it. Thanks in advance

```
Do While Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(lin_dest_1, 1) = ""

    Select Case True

    Case Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(lin_dest_1, 1).Value2 = "":

    If Sheets("Mono risco 3").Cells(lin_ori_1, 1) <> "" Then

        Do While Sheets("Mono risco 3").Cells(lin_ori_1, 1) <> ""

            Do While Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 1) <> ""

                Select Case True

                Case Sheets("Mono risco 3").Cells(lin_ori_1, 1) = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 1):


                    Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(lin_dest_1, 1).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori, 1).Value2
                    Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(lin_dest_1, 2).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori, 2).Value2
                    Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(lin_dest_1, 3).Value2 = "Mono Bi"
                    Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(lin_dest_1, 4).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori, 4).Value2
                    Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(lin_dest_1, 5).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori, 5).Value2
                    Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(lin_dest_1, 6).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori, 6).Value2
                    Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(lin_dest_1, 7).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori, 7).Value2
                    lin_ori_1 = lin_ori_1 + 2

                Case Else


                    lin_ori_2 = lin_ori_2 + 1


                End Select
                Loop
                Loop

    Case Else: lin_dest_1 = lin_dest_1 + 1

    End Select


    '
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you replace your code with the following, it should work as you expect (this assumes that both "Mono risco 3" and "MonoBi" have headers):

```
Sub foo()
MonoRiscoLastRow = Sheets("Mono risco 3").Cells(Sheets("Mono risco 3").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row on column A of Sheet Mono risco 3
MonoBiLastRow = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(Sheets("MonoBi").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row on column A of Sheet MonoBi

For i = 2 To MonoRiscoLastRow 'loop through Mono Risco
    For x = 2 To MonoBiLastRow 'loop through MonoBi
        If Sheets("Mono risco 3").Cells(i, 1).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(x, 1).Value2 Then 'do your comparison, if equal then
        BiRecursoNextRow = Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(Sheets("Bi recurso").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'get next empty row on column A of Sheet Bi Recurso
            For y = 1 To 7
                Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(BiRecursoNextRow, y).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(x, y).Value2
            Next y
            Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(BiRecursoNextRow, 3).Value2 = "Mono Bi"
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I didn't know that was possible to "calculate" the number of rows or columns different from 0. This is a simple method that helped me a lot. Thank you. The code you posted is not exactly the solution to my problem but i just adapted it to my Workbook and it is working fine. I'll post the final solution (with while cycles yet, i'll change it to for later :) )

Comment: I'm glad my suggestion helped you, please could you mark my response as an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution after your suggestion:

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro_monos_monobi()
'
' macro_monos_monobi Macro
'

Dim lin_ori_1 As Integer
Dim lin_ori_2 As Integer
Dim BirecursoNextRow As Integer

lin_ori_1 = 2
lin_ori_2 = 2


BirecursoNextRow = Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(Sheets("Bi recurso").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Sheets("Mono risco 3").Cells(lin_ori_1, 1) <> "" Then

    Do While Sheets("Mono risco 3").Cells(lin_ori_1, 1) <> ""

        Do While Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 1) <> ""

            Select Case True

            Case Sheets("Mono risco 3").Cells(lin_ori_1, 1) = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 1):


                Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(BirecursoNextRow, 1).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 1).Value2
                Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(BirecursoNextRow, 2).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 2).Value2
                Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(BirecursoNextRow, 3).Value2 = "Mono Bi"
                Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(BirecursoNextRow, 4).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 4).Value2
                Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(BirecursoNextRow, 5).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 5).Value2
                Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(BirecursoNextRow, 6).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 6).Value2
                Sheets("Bi recurso").Cells(BirecursoNextRow, 7).Value2 = Sheets("MonoBi").Cells(lin_ori_2, 7).Value2
                lin_ori_1 = lin_ori_1 + 2
                BirecursoNextRow = BirecursoNextRow + 1

            Case Else:

                lin_ori_2 = lin_ori_2 + 1

            End Select

            Loop
                lin_ori_2 = 2
            Loop

End If


'
End Sub
```

Comment: Good adaptation from my suggestion, remember that lin_ori_1 and the other variables should be declared as 'Long'

Comment: Hello why should i use Long instead of Integer? Couldn't understand that

Comment: Because there are more cells in excel than there are integer values, so to avoid any errors in the future when you might have more data, you should declare your variables as Long.. Hope that makes sense..